# Record AAC or OPUS enocded audio using QAudioRecorder

Tags: qt

`QAudioRecorder::supportedAudioCodecs` gives me only `"audio/pcm"`. Is it possible to add `"audio/aac"` and `"audio/opus"` using libfaac and libopus respectively? What is the proper way of doing this? My system is Windows 8-10.